# Not Really Into Pokemon

Tags: riddle, knowledge, steganography, video-games

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

> I'm not really into Pokemon, you see
>   But a friend of mine is, as much as can be.
>   He goes on and on about this move and that,
>   And I can't be bothered to remember the smallest fact.
>   Recently, he described to me
>   A Pokemon quite intriguing.
>
> He said it was brutal and ruthless,
>   And that it was constantly attacking.
>   Curious despite myself, I want to see it.
>
> What does this Pokemon look like, exactly?
>   The only other detail I have, however
>   Is that it has decent power.
>   Oh, I almost forgot, he also told me
>   That it can be found, at least originally, only by evolving.

Can you help me figure out what Pokemon "my friend" was talking about? I need only the name, from there I can search to figure out what it looks like myself!

Comment: I might have the 'mon pinned down... now to try and see what that steganography tag has to do with it!

Comment: @Teo Only a major hint... It's really not a super subtle hint, though it's definitely easy to overlook. :) It'll practically hand you the answer on a silver platter if you catch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be

> Hydreigon

According to the pokemon entry in black

> Hydreigon, the Brutal Pokémon and the evolved form of Zweilous. Hydreigon uses its six wings to travel the skies. It will attack anything that moves, seeing it as an opponent.

This is a pseudo-legendary pokemon with decent/good attack/sp.attack

In gen 5, this pokemon could only be attained by evolving :

> Zweilous

**EDIT**

The last part of the puzzle, given to me/ figured out by @hagfy:

> The number of lines, in each section becomes the pokedex number. #635

Comment: This is the correct Pokemon! You did miss the stenography clue, so I'm inclined to wait to accept in case someone catches that in a later answer, but otherwise you've got all the clues on the nose.

Comment: Haha - The question says : `"I need only the name"` :-D

Comment: The name is the correct answer, true, but the accept is generally for what the OP considers the "best answer". In this case, there's a little more of hints (Well, a single other hint) to be explained- If no one else catches it, you'll get the accept. If someone does before too long, they'll get it for the "best" answer. (Likewise, if you catch it and edit it in, then I won't bother waiting, you'll have the best possible answer.)

Comment: It's fine ;) I can't see it. 
Good luck people!

Comment: Is it a riddle on, who you and the friend are?

Comment: No, I am the "friend" because I'm a huge Pokenerd. :) That was just a good way for me to present the puzzle. It's just a hidden bit of styling or punctuation... Something about how I presented the puzzle that gives a huge clue to the Pokemon.

Comment: @Stender I think they're referring to rot13(gur ahzore bs yvarf va rnpu frpgvba, fvk guerr svir, juvpu vf ulqervtba'f cbxrqrk ahzore).  You nailed the rest of it, so you're welcome to just edit this in.  Nice work!

Comment: @hagfy Nailed it!

Comment: @hagfy would never have thought of that :) Nice eye!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be...

> Pangoro? (https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pangoro_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

He said it was brutal and ruthless, 
And that it was constantly attacking.

> "Despite its cantankerous demeanor, Pangoro is not one to tolerate those who pick on the weak. With arms powerful enough to snap a telephone pole, it charges into battle like a berserker, heedless of any damage it might suffer as it bashes its opponents."

The only other detail I have, however 
Is that it has decent power.

> "Decent" is an understatement. It has very high attack stats.

Oh, I almost forgot, he also told me
That it can be found, at least originally, only by evolving.

> "It evolves from Pancham starting at level 32, if the player has a Dark-type Pokémon in their party".

Comment: A very good guess! There's a Pokemon that fits the clues better, however, with a Pokedex entry that more closely matches those two lines. :) (I also wouldn't call a Pokemon that hates people picking on the weak "brutal and ruthless", but that might just be me.)

Comment: Also, as a heads up, I completely forgot a tag that _might_ help you sort out the answer. My apologies!

Comment: I could be wrong, but i interpret the last line of the riddle to mean that it was in pokemon gen 1, and was only available through evolving in that generation, but in later generations it could be found in the wild.

Comment: @Dragonrage A very close interpretation of that line- It's more meant to show that it's not a new (Gen 7) Pokemon, but not eliminate the other generations.